# The email address is badly formatted Firebase (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I’ve read all the related posts and answers here and haven’t found a solution for myself. I have several classes for email and password validation, also there is verification for characters and password length, I can successfully register a new user, but I can not log in to an account under the email and password of a newly registered user because I get this error:  `Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - The email address is badly formatted.`
Also using the `print` I checked that gets on the input to the function and transferred to the firebase when trying to sign in and I found that there are no extra spaces, incorrect characters and so on. My code looks like this:

```
class Validator {
  final _emailRules =
  RegExp(r'^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$');
  final _passwordRules = RegExp(r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$');

  String validateEmail(String email) {
    if (email.isEmpty) {
      return 'Email cannot be empty';
    } else if (!_emailRules.hasMatch(email)) {
      return 'Please enter a valid email';
    }
    return '';
  }

  String validatePassword(String password) {
    if (password.isEmpty) {
      return 'Password cannot be empty';
    } else if (!_passwordRules.hasMatch(password)) {
      return 'Password should be 8 digit, uppercase letters';
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```

sign in method:

```
  Future<User?> signInUser(String email, String password) async {
    UserCredential userCredential = await _firebase.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email.trim(), password: password.trim());
    User? user = userCredential.user;
    if (user != null) {
      String token = await user.getIdToken();
      await storage.write(key: 'token', value: token);
    }
    return user;
  }
```

checking for  password/emeil inputs are correct

```
 bool _validateFields(BuildContext context) {
    String emailError = Validator().validateEmail(_emailController.text);
    String passwordError = Validator().validatePassword(_passwordController.text);

    if (emailError.isNotEmpty) {
      showSnackBarError(context, emailError);
      return false;
    }

    if (passwordError.isNotEmpty) {
      showSnackBarError(context, passwordError);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

at least the bloc of code with sending to Firebase email/password:

```
 SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_validateFields(context)) {
                    String email = _emailController.text.trim();
                    String password = _passwordController.text;
                    BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context).add(
                      SignInEvent(email: email, password: password),
                    );
                    print(email);
                    print(password);
                  }
                },
                child: const Text('Sign In'),
              ),
            )
```

But then I use hardcoded value for email/password in signIn method (previously added it in Firebase) it works perfectly well.

**EDIT**: I found solution and I was pretty dumb. I was mixed up places of password and login in place where I refer to  `signInUser`. All I should to do is fix the problem and it worked. it **was**   final

```
userSignIn = await fireBaseService.signInUser(
           event.password, event.email);
```

**BUT it should be**  final

```
userSignIn = await fireBaseService.signInUser(
            event.email, event.password);
```

Comment: Where do you call `signInUser` and what value are you passing as `email` parameter. Set a breakpoint directly in that method and check the value of `email`

Comment: All I had to do was notice that I mixed up the email and the password, because at the point where I refer to the signInUser method, I mixed up the email and password positions. I was dumb

Comment: No, please don't use this regex to validate email.  It's wrong.  The shortest regex to validate an RFC822 email address is about 2400 characters, and is given in https://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html.  Anything shorter is WRONG, unless you're using a grammar, as package:email_validator properly does.  Use that for Dart/Flutter please.

Answer (score 1):

The error basically implies that the email entered is not a proper format that is accepted by firebase.

As suggested in the above comment add a breakpoint before sending the email to firebase and print the email value.

Another small suggestion that I would like to add is to use a package for validating your email called [email_validator](https://pub.dev/packages/email_validator). I have never had to worry about validating the email and simply use this package.

P.s. If the validator is working correctly then you will not require to trim the value anymore.

Here is the simple usage of email validator:

```
TextFormField(
...
validator: (value){
 if (EmailValidator.validate(value!)) { 
  return null;
  } else {
  return "Please enter a valid email";
  }
},
...
),
```

Hope this helps you out!